# heroku app crashes because of missing module, but works on localhost

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose

I have an app that I successfully deployed to heroku, but when I try to access it, I get this screen...
[image]

The log says the following...[image]

The error I believe is causing the issue is `Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'`.

Here is my package.json for reference...

```js
{
  "name": "ovo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "see and sort OVO in real time!",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js",
    "dev": "concurrently -k \"npm run frontend\" \"npm run backend\"",
    "frontend": "webpack -d --watch",
    "backend": "nodemon server.js",
    "start": "npm run build && NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register ./test/**/*.js --require ignore-styles"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.0",
    "npm": "5.0.3"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/leojacoby/ovo.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.8.1",
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.6.5",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "rc-slider": "^8.6.0",
    "rc-tooltip": "^3.7.0",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^0.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
    "eslint-watch": "^3.1.0",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.5.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.5.4",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/leojacoby/ovo/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/leojacoby/ovo#readme",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "keywords": []
}
```

The 'mongoose' npm package is in my package.json, and everything works just fine when I run it on my localhost.  Please let me know if you want any more information and thank you for reading!

Comment: Is `package.json` in your project root directory?

Comment: Yes `package.json` is in my root directory

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I hadn't connected my github to my heroku.  I was pushing to github but it was not updating heroku so I kept experiencing the same errors.  This is what I had to enable in heroku and then my edits actually manifested in the heroku.
[image]

An alternative is to just type in `git push heroku master` into the terminal everytime.

The last thing I had to do was type in `heroku config:set MONGODB_URI='mongodb://<name>:<password>@ds123050.mlab.com:23050/ovodb'` into the terminal for heroku to access my environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pushing node_modules in your code? If yes try to delete that folder and let Heroku install all modules all over again.

Comment: Also, make sure to track your `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` so Heroku can install the exact versions of your dependencies that you're using in development.

Comment: I had `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` in my `.gitignore` file but I took out `package-lock.json` and then tried again, but it still didn't work.